# see values from one table that appear on another table

Tags: java, sql, db2

I have 2 tables,

```
'prodAtt'
attID, prodID
218,   11
219,   11
220,   10
221,   10
222,   15
223,   15

'attrdef'
attID, attName
218,    a
219,    b
220,    c
221,    e
222,    f
223,    g
```

i want to see all attrdef rows that have a prodID or 10 or 11

I have tried

```
select * from ATTRdEF inner JOIN PRODATT on PRODATT.PRODUCT_ID = 11 or PRODATT.PRODUCT_ID = 10
```

but this returns the entire **attrdef** table, i am using squirrel and its a DB2 database.

can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify how the table `prodAtt` should be joined with the table `attrdef`, so any filtering you try to achieve by joining another table is without effect. You have to tell your DB on which columns you wish to join the two tables, then you can add your `WHERE`-clause to filter the results.

Looking at the tables, you should join them on the column `attID`:

```
 SELECT a.attID
      , a.attName
 FROM ATTRDEF a
      INNER JOIN PRODATT p ON a.ATTID = p.ATTID
 WHERE p.prodID IN (10, 11);
```

Comment: thanks, both worked for me, but this explained what i was doing wrong, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try with,

```
 SELECT * FROM 
     ATTRDEF a INNER JOIN PRODATT p 
         ON a.ATTID = p.ATTID
 WHERE p.PRODID IN (10, 11);
```

Or,

```
SELECT * FROM 
    ATTRDEF a, PRODATT p
WHERE a.ATTID = p.ATTID 
    AND a.PRODID IN (10, 11);
```